# How to find the answer for unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

Full Question Here:

> For what values of $\mu$, the system of equations $x+y+z=1, \ x+2y+4z= \mu$ and $x+4y+10z = \mu^2$ got (i) unique solution (ii) infinite solution (iii) no solution.

I have reduced the above matrix to echelon form and seems that the first 3 elements of the last column are 0. How can i get the values for a unique solution

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Can you answer (ii) and (iii)?  Are there any other values of $\mu$ and if so how many solutions do they give?

Comment: The last element if the 3rd row will be a equation with root 2 and 1.So if the μ is 2 and 1 the last row will be 0.Since the rank(A) and rank(AB) is less than n=3 ,for that condition there will be infinite solutions